# windows: if ReadFile fails, can I ReadFile again?

Tags: windows, file-io

I am using the Windows ReadFile function to read a large file.

If the network is not so stable, at times I will get an error when calling ReadFile (network location no longer available).  At the moment, if this happens I just error out and terminate my process.

What if, when ReadFile fails, I just wait a few seconds and try again?  Assuming the network issue went away, would I get the right data from ReadFile?  Or at that point does it forget where in the file it tries to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ReadFile` failed because the network share went away, you most likely will have to reopen the file when it comes back.